# Custom package with dependency init error: ModuleNotFoundError or ImportError

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm creating a custom package that has the following structure:

```
test_package
    │   README.md
    │   setup.py
    │
    ├───my_package
    │       my_package.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    └───tests
            tests.py
```

My package depends on pygdbmi, so I added it to the list of required dependencies.

I'm using `__init__.py` to import the modules

`__init__.py`:

```py
from .my_package import my_class

__version__ = '0.0.1'
__title__ = 'my_package'
```

And my class is:

`my_package.py`:

```py
from pygdbmi.gdbcontroller import GdbController

class my_class:
    def __init__(self):
        print("my_class!!")
        self.gdbmi = GdbController()
```

The problem is that when I run `python setup.py install clean`, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
python setup.py install clean
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import my_package
  File "c:\test_package\my_package\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .my_package import my_class
  File "c:\test_package\my_package\my_package.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pygdbmi.gdbcontroller import GdbController
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygdbmi
```

Which is obvious, because `__init__` is importing `my_package`, it breaks because I don't have pygdbmi installed yet.

I tried to fix this by removing the import from `__init__.py`:

```py
__version__ = '0.0.1'
__title__ = 'my_package'
```

It installs correctly, but now I can't import my package. when I try to run some tests:

```
python tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from my_package import my_class
ImportError: cannot import name 'my_class' from 'my_package' (C:\Users\lalalala\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3-32\lib\site-packages\my_package-0.0.1-py3.7.egg\my_package\__init__.py)
```

How do I fix this? I'd like to keep the `__init__` structure of defining the version, etc, as it seems the Pythonic way to do it.

Many thanks!!!

`setup.py`:

```py
import setuptools
import my_package

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    # Project information
    name=my_package.__title__,
    version=my_package.__version__,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=["pygdbmi"],
    python_requires='>=3.7',
    # Tests
    test_suite='tests'
)
```

`my_package.py`:

```py
from pygdbmi.gdbcontroller import GdbController

class my_class:
    def __init__(self):
        print("my_class!!")
        self.gdbmi = GdbController()
```

`tests.py`:

```py
import unittest

from my_package import my_class

class some_test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_constructor(self):
        self.assertIsNotNone(my_class())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I fix this? I'd like to keep the `__init__` structure of defining the version, etc, as it seems the Pythonic way to do it.

It is not, name and version are package metadata, which does not belong into the source code. It belongs into your package definition, meaning `setup.py` in your case.

Your `__init__.py` should work the other way round, and get its info from interacting with the python environment and its own installation:

```
from importlib import metadata

# this works, but usually people just write the name as a string here.
# not 100% DRY, but it's not like the package name could ever change
__title__ = __name__
# if you're stuck on python 3.7 or older, importlib-metadata is a 
# third-party package that can be used as a drop-in instead
__version__ = metadata.version(__title__)
```

---

The most important take-away message should be that you should never import your code into your build-script. It can 1) create nasty chicken-egg problems where your code can't be built unless an older version of it was installed already, and 2) turn all your run-time dependencies into built-time dependencies, which is what you're experiencing.

You may be able to work around both of these problem, but the easier way would be to set up your package data in the way described above, and never get the issue in the first place.

Comment: Thanks very much! This is a very elegant solution. What kind of metadata is usually included in `__init__.py`?

Comment: I personally only have the version in there, because that's the only one I end up actually using within my code.