# Python Custom package import module name not importing on init

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm creating a custom package with the following structure:

```
test_package
    │   README.md
    │   setup.py
    │
    ├───my_package
    │       my_package.py
    │       __init__.py
    │
    └───tests
            tests.py
```

When importing `my_package`, I have to use

```py
from my_package.my_package import my_class

o = my_class()
```

Or

```py
import my_package

my_package.my_package.my_class()
```

How can I use just `from my_package import my_class` **WITHOUT** adding imports to `__init__.py`? I can't do that because [my package has dependency on pygdbmi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64719691/6271889).

I'm using setuptools.

Many thanks!!

```py
import setuptools
import my_package

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    # Project information
    name=my_package.__title__,
    version=my_package.__version__,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=["pygdbmi"],
    python_requires='>=3.7',
    # Tests
    test_suite='tests'
)
```

`__init__.py`:

```py
__version__ = '0.0.1'
__title__ = 'my_package'
```

`my_package.py`

```py
from pygdbmi.gdbcontroller import GdbController

class my_class:
    def __init__(self):
        print("my_class!!")
        self.gdbmi = GdbController()
```

`tests.py`:

```py
import unittest

from my_package.my_package import my_class

class some_test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_constructor(self):
        self.assertIsNotNone(my_class())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: why don't you just distribute `my_package.py`, without putting it in a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate my comment,

`my_package.py`:

```
from pygdbmi.gdbcontroller import GdbController

__version__ = '0.0.1'
__title__ = 'my_package'

class my_class:
    def __init__(self):
        print("my_class!!")
```

`setup.py`:

```
# ...

setuptools.setup(
    # Project information
    name=my_package.__title__,
    version=my_package.__version__,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    py_modules=['my_package'],  # replaces `packages=setuptools.find_packages(),`
    install_requires=["pygdbmi"],
    python_requires='>=3.7',
    # Tests
    test_suite='tests'
)
```